# Locus in the complex plane given an equation

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, locus

I have the question

> Let $a$ and $e$ be two positive real numbers, with $0 < e < 1$. Describe the locus of the points $z$ in the complex plane which satisfy $|z - ae| + |z + ae| = 2a$.

I know this equation is telling me

(distance from *z* to (*ae*, 0)) + (distance from (*x*, *y*) to ($-ae$, 0) = 2a

and I know that $0 < e < a$ and $ae < a$.

Inspecting a graph thus reveals two solutions: $z = a$ and $z = -a$. But I haven't been able to make more headway than this.

Will I have to resort to algebra (which looks very messy indeed), or is there a more elegant geometric solution that you can point out?

Comment: The locus is an ellipse, but I fear you can't avoid the algebra.

Comment: Yeah, the algebra isn't looking too bad after all, it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> distance from *z* to $(ae,0)$ + distance from $(x,y)$ to $(−ae,0)=2a$

...and the geometric shape defined by the property that the sum of the two distances from each of its points to two fixed points (called *foci*) is constant is called by *what* name exactly... ? :-)